# Emacs opens Windows network logon prompt

Tags: windows, emacs

I recently, for work reasons, had to switch back from using Linux to using Windows on my laptop. I have not changed my emacs configuration in any way, but now when I start up emacs, twice I get a "Windows Security" network login prompt for a server I previously had mapped a shared folder to. Ever since I deleted that shared folder, emacs now prompts me twice during the startup sequence to log into the server. Nothing in my config files points to this server, and I don't have this problem on any other machine where I use the same configuration.

Any idea why this might be happening and how to make it stop?

EDIT:

I've identified one line of the config file that triggers it. It's

```
(setq org-completion-use-ido t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(setq ido-max-directory-size 100000)
(ido-mode (quote both)) ;; Evaluating this line pulls it up.
```

Comment: Are you using `recentf`, or something that saves your open files like [Desktop](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop)?

Comment: Start emacs with `emacs -Q`. If the problem disappears with this switch it lies within your config files. As Chris pointed out it may be that you load recently opened files through some package.

Comment: I'm sure it's my config files, though I'm not using `recentf` or anything else that saves my files that I'm aware of. Is there a common place to store cache files for programs like that that I could clear?

Comment: If it works with `emacs -Q` and the usual suspects don't pan out, then it may be time to start bisecting your configuration files by commenting out entire sections in order to locate the problem.

Comment: @lawlist I've found one of the culprits and edited it into the question above. Seems it's something to do with IDO. Is there a way I can clear its cache so it's not trying to look at this external server?

Comment: How about the file where the variable `ido-save-directory-list-file` points, or something of that nature?

Comment: Worked like magic. I deleted my `.ido.last` and everything is awesome. Go ahead and make that an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the original poster having narrowed down the issue to `ido-mode`, the likely suspect is the file where the variable `ido-save-directory-list-file` points to.

The printout for `describe-variable` of the aforementioned variable is as follows:

```
ido-save-directory-list-file is a variable defined in `ido.el'.
Its value is "~/.emacs.d/ido.last"

Documentation:
File in which the Ido state is saved between invocations.
Variables stored are: `ido-last-directory-list', `ido-work-directory-list',
`ido-work-file-list', and `ido-dir-file-cache'.
Must be set before enabling Ido mode.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 24.4 of Emacs.
```